# What does "automatic" mean under Network restrictions?

Tags: wi-fi, 8.1-oreo

I'm running Android Oreo 8.1 on a Pixel XL. When I go to Settings > Network & Internet > Data usage > Network restrictions, I notice that all of my saved wifi networks are listed. Under each one, it says "Automatic". When I select one of the networks in the list, I see "Automatic", "Metered", and "Not metered". What does "Automatic" mean in this context?

Comment: As per [this](https://www.bestusefultips.com/set-metered-wi-fi-network-on-android-oreo/) , if you set up metered WiFi , new WiFi are automatically added to metered by choosing the automatic option. You may try

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can tell from looking at the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/093ade312d402c3453663db746d1f90787890d2b/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.java#772), "Automatic" means the network is metered if it meets at least one of these heuristics:

- The WifiConfiguration has a metered hint, which I assume can be done if the network is added by an app.
- The network has an "Ant" (802.11u access network type) of PublicChargeable ([code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/f24354dfb99eca9de897e258f3818045c9464eab/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#3330)).
- The DHCP server sent the `ANDROID_METERED` option ([code 1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/f24354dfb99eca9de897e258f3818045c9464eab/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#3538), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/093ade312d402c3453663db746d1f90787890d2b/core/java/android/net/DhcpResults.java#73)), which [the Android hotspot itself sends](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/9d2a53f8b6eb637891a5767ecb1e3e609930c56e/server/TetherController.cpp#223).  [Additional commentary](https://www.lorier.net/docs/android-metered).

(I found the code links by searching the [LineageOS source code on GitHub](https://github.com/LineageOS/) and opening the corresponding AOSP files, since the AOSP repository browser doesn't appear to support searching; maybe there's another way.)